# how to write immediately search (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I'm using visual web developer to create basic gui with one table DB.
I'm trying to make something like google instant search.
I have a search page that contains one textbox, one button, and gridview.  I'm entering a string in the textbox, pressing the button and getting the results in the gridview.

I'm trying to use the `textchanged` event of the textbox and allow autopostback but still the search isn't working as I want.

What am I missing and how can I create the search as showed above?

Comment: You'll need a lot of great [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to do something like that. So if you don't know about Ajax, learn that first.

Comment: Please elaborate in as much detail as possible what you mean by "not working."

Comment: i mean that i need to press to button to active the search instead of the search will be active by the textchanged event, 
there isnt simplest way to write this?(without ajax :S)

Answer (score 3):

We implemented a Google Instant type of search using the following:

1. **TypeWatch Plugin:** The [TypeWatch plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch) raises an event x milliseconds after the user stops typing in the text box.  Can be configured to activate after a number of characters have been typed.
2. **A server-side Search function:** Implement your search and expose it in a url in your site so you can submit searches and return **json** objects with the result.
3. **An Ajax call:** When the typewatch event is raised, make the ajax call to the Search endpoint, and render the results.